# Find word in random string

Tags: java, string

Say I have a string that may look like:

"RAHDTWUOPO"

I know the word I'm looking for, for example:

"WORD"

what would be the best method for finding if I can make up "WORD" with a string like "RAHDTWUOPO"

EDIT:

Because of this question being unclear Id thought Id put more detail. What I wanted to achieve was to find if a word I knew beforehand could be made up from a random string of letters. Wasn't sure how to go about this, with a loop or if there was some other method.

I had come up with something quickly in my head but I knew it was to much effort, but I'll put it here to make this question more clearer of what I wanted to achieve.

```
public class MyLetterObject {
    private String letter;
    private Boolean used;

    public String getText() {
        return letter;
    }

    public void setLetter(String letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public Boolean getUsed() {
        return used;
    }

    public void setUsed(Boolean used) {
        this.used = used;
    }
}

boolean ContainsWord(String Word, String RandomLetterString) {
    List<MyLetterObject> MyLetterList = new ArrayList<MyLetterObject>();
    for (char ch : RandomLetterString.toCharArray()) {
        MyLetterObject mlo = new MyLetterObject();
        mlo.setLetter(String.valueOf(ch));
        mlo.setUsed(false);
        MyLetterList.add(mlo);
    }

    String sMatch = "";

    for (char Wordch : Word.toCharArray()) {

        for (MyLetterObject o : MyLetterList) {

            if (o.getUsed() == false
                    && String.valueOf(Wordch).equals(o.getText())) {

                o.setUsed(true);
                sMatch = sMatch + String.valueOf(Wordch);
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    if (sMatch.equals(Word)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see to much effort. Evgeniy Dorofeev answer is much more better for the purpose of just finding if a word can be made from a string made up of letters in a random order.

Comment: What approaches have you considered so far?

Comment: It's gonna take permutations and blah forget it. It's too complicated for a person who hasn't done anything to tackle it.

Comment: do you know [String.indexOf(String str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
boolean containsWord(String s, String w) {
    List<Character> list = new LinkedList<Character>();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        list.add(c);
    }
    for (Character c : w.toCharArray()) {
        if (!list.remove(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You search every letter, one by one in the first String.

```
 String randomString = "RAHDTWUOPO";
 String word = "WORD";

 for(int i=0;i<word.length; i++){
      if(randomString.contains(word.charAt(i))){

         // Yey, another letter found
      }
 }
```

Then you only have to test if for every `i` the letter was actually found, if not, the word is not included in the randomString.

Answer (score 0):

You need find, that all letters from your word "WORD" exists in input string at list once. 
Simple loop will do it for you  but performance will not be best one.
You can use guava library multiset: 
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

Multiset wordsMultiset = HashMultiset.create();wordsMultiset.addAll(words);// now we can use wordsMultiset.count(String) to find the count of a word

This example is about words, adopte it to chars of your input string.